# How to get a particular data from a table which has XML Data

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

This is the Query i'm using to get the data from the XML which is stored in a column of table x.

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE (IT.ADO_DATA, '/valueXML/IndividualADO/ado-name') "REFERENCE"
  FROM ITEM_ADO IT
```

and here is the XML data

```
<valueXML xmlns="com.ado" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <IndividualADO>
    <ado-name>LIMS</ado-name>
    <field>
      <ado-field-name>ADO_LIMS_LIMS_Custodian_First_Name</ado-field-name>
      <ado-field-value xsi:nil="true"/>
    </field>
  </IndividualADO>
</valueXML>
```

I'm trying to fetch the data of node "ado-name"

Comment: What happens when you run that query? Do you get an error, or just no the result you expect? What data type is the ASO_DATA column?

Comment: I dint get any results when i execute the above query and data type of ADO_DATA is XML TYPE

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ADO_DATA` is of type XMLType, your current query will get no value back because your `valueXML` node has namespace, which you need to include in the XPath, or use a wildcard:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE (IT.ADO_DATA, '/*:valueXML/*:IndividualADO/*:ado-name') "REFERENCE"
  FROM ITEM_ADO IT;

REFERENCE                                                                      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LIMS
```

But [`extractvalue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions061.htm) is depcreated; you can do the same with [an XQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm):

```
select xmlquery(
  '/*:valueXML/*:IndividualADO/*:ado-name/text()'
  passing ado_data
  returning content) as reference
from item_ado;

REFERENCE                                                                      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LIMS
```

Or with a default namespace instead of the wildcard (and showing the CTE used for testing):

```
with item_ado (ado_data) as (
  select xmltype('<valueXML xmlns="com.ado" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <IndividualADO>
    <ado-name>LIMS</ado-name>
    <field>
      <ado-field-name>ADO_LIMS_LIMS_Custodian_First_Name</ado-field-name>
      <ado-field-value xsi:nil="true"/>
    </field>
  </IndividualADO>
</valueXML>') from dual
)
select xmlquery(
  'declare default element namespace "com.ado"; (: :)
    /valueXML/IndividualADO/ado-name/text()'
  passing ado_data
  returning content) as reference
from item_ado;

REFERENCE                                                                      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LIMS
```

Comment: The above query dint get what i was expecting. i have to click on the row to know the data. There are lot of data in the table.

Comment: A lot of rows with one ado-name per XML; or many ado-name nodes in each XML document?